# str object has no attribute random *python2.7*

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error, attributeerror

I wrote this and obviously I messed up somewhere.

I got errors at lines 57 and 38 (essentially whenever it tried assigning a new name to variable `itemname`)

```
import random

def createitem():

    weapon = ['sword', 'dagger', 'axe']
    armor = ['cloth armor', 'chainmail', 'leather armor', 'full plate']

    magicpre = ['shining', 'burning', 'aether', 'fine']
    magicsuf = ['of the bear', 'of the wolf', 'of the jackal']
    magictag = '*MAGIC*'

    rarepre = ['angelic', 'demonic', 'blessed', 'cursed', 'masterwork']
    raresuf = ['of heaven', 'of hell', 'of the king', 'of the chimera']
    raretag = '*RARE*'

    pendingitem = []

    itemname = ''

    appenditem = pendingitem.append(itemname)

    aq = random.randint(0,5)


    for num in range(0, aq):

        weporarm = random.randint(0,1)
        raritycheck = random.randint(0,5)
        preorsuf = random.randint(0,1)

        if weporarm == 1:
            if raritycheck == 5:
                itemname = raretag, random.choice(rarepre), random.choice(armor), random.choice(raresuf)
            elif raritycheck == 4 and preorsuf == 2:
                itemname = raretag, random.choice(armor), random.choice(raresuf)
            elif raritycheck == 4 and preorsuf == 1:
                itemname = raretag, random.choice(rarepre), random.choice(armor)
            elif raritycheck == 3:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre), random.choice(armor). random.choice(magicsuf)
            elif raritycheck == 2 and preorsuf == 0:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre), random.choice(armor)
            elif raritycheck == 2 and preorsuf == 1:
                itemname = magictag, randcom.choice(armor), random.choice(magicsuf)
            elif raritycheck == 1 and preorsuf == 0:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre). random.choice(armor)
            elif raritycheck == 1 and preorsuf == 1:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(armor), random.choice(magicsuf)
            else:
                itemname = random.choice(armor)
        else:
            if raritycheck == 5:
                itemname = raretag, random.choice(rarepre), random.choice(weapon), random.choice(raresuf)
            elif raritycheck == 4 and preorsuf == 2:
                itemname = raretag, random.choice(weapon), random.choice(raresuf)
            elif raritycheck == 4 and preorsuf == 1:
                itemname = raretag, random.choice(rarepre), random.choice(weapon)
            elif raritycheck == 3:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre), random.choice(weapon). random.choice(magicsuf)
            elif raritycheck == 2 and preorsuf == 0:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre), random.choice(weapon)
            elif raritycheck == 2 and preorsuf == 1:
                itemname = magictag, randcom.choice(weapon), random.choice(magicsuf)
            elif raritycheck == 1 and preorsuf == 0:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre). random.choice(weapon)
            elif raritycheck == 1 and preorsuf == 1:
                itemname = magictag, random.choice(weapon), random.choice(magicsuf)
            else:
                itemname = random.choice(weapon)

    appenditem
    a = str(pendingitem)
    print('Your inventory:', a)
```

Comment: Your question title does not seem to be related to the bold description. What exactly is the problem? What error message do you get?

Comment: What error message? Which are lines 57 and 38?

Answer (score 2):

You have a period (`.`) instead of a comma (`,`) on these two lines, which causes python to interpret the `random` after it as an attribute of the previous variable, which, of course, fails.

```
itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre), random.choice(armor). random.choice(magicsuf)
# Here -----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Just replace it with a comma and you should be fine:

```
itemname = magictag, random.choice(magicpre), random.choice(armor), random.choice(magicsuf)
# Here -----------------------------------------------------------^
```